# How to get HTML url from Websphere Portal server?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-7, websphere-portal, websphere-9

I made a new url page in Portal administration, now I want this link (not a decoded one, exactly the string in text box) in my java code. How can I get it?

Image of the field, which I want value of
[image: Image of the field, which I want value of]

Comment: If you want to access portal page information through Java, I think you might have to use the [Content Model](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.5.0/mp/dev/dgn_modelpkg.html#modelapic__content) of the [Model SPI](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.5.0/mp/dev/dgn_modelovw.html).

Comment: Yes I know it is somehow possible, but I can’t figure it out. a little code example will be nice.